# TimeStrings to Seconds in VBA

Tags: vba

I have this timestrings:

```
"01-Jan-2013 00:00:00.000"
"02-Jan-2013 00:00:00.000"
```

In VBA, how can I calculate the difference in seconds between them?

I thought about converting them to seconds then getting the differene form it, is there a way of converting a string to seconds? Or there's a better way of calculating the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chop off the milliseconds part and `DateDiff`:

```
diff = DateDiff("s", Left$("01-Jan-2013 00:00:00.000", 20), Left$("02-Jan-2013 00:00:00.000", 20))
```